# Request timed out - Request timed out

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-7, windows-server-2008

My website is running on Asp.net v4 , IIS 7 , Windows server 2008.

My cpu is running on 20-30% and the site is responding quickly.

Every 2-5 mins I'm receiving the following error:

```
Event code: 3001 
Event message: The request has been aborted. 
Exception type: HttpException 
Exception message: Request timed out. , 

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://www.xxxx.com/Services/AxRefresh.asmx/AxUpdate 
    Request path: /Services/AxRefresh.asmx/AxUpdate 
    User host address: 84.110.251.198 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
```

i read that the error is related to the maximum concurrent requests limit
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268

but then i found out that on IIS 7 this limitation is changed and not relevant.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560842(VS.100).aspx

Any other ideas what can be the problem or where to start looking ?

**update:**
found another link saying that all the below parameters:
maxWorkerThreads
minWorkerThreads
maxIoThreads
minFreeThreads
minLocalRequestFreeThreads
maxconnection
executionTimeout

are NOT relevant for IIS7+Asp.NET 4

here is the link
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/381/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis-70

**I still get the 100's errors daily on my iis7 **

Comment: http://www.xxxx.com/Services/AxRefresh.asmx/AxUpdate  
run it on your test machine and use Stopwatch to find what is slow.

Answer (score 0):

The second link you found has no relationship with the first one, so you still need to apply the changes in the first article and see if it helps.

Comment: see this link : http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/381/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis-70.

ASP.NET threading settings are not used to control the request concurrency in Integrated mode
The minFreeThreads, minLocalRequestFreeThreads settings in the system.web/httpRuntime configuration section and the maxWorkerThreads setting in the processModel configuration section no longer control the threading mechanism used by ASP.NET. Instead, ASP.NET relies on the IIS thread pool and allows you to control the maximum number of concurrently executing requests by setting the MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU.